# How to connect a Windows print driver pipeline filter [C++/C] [WDK]

Tags: windows, printing, driver, wdk

I am looking into building a pipeline filter for a Windows printer driver (first time dabbling in the WDK) and unfortunately there are very few resources and examples that show how to do this. There is one example provided in the WDK [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/SimplePipelineFilter) and there are resources I have been referring to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/xps-filters). I have built and have been trying to attach the sample pipeline filter to the basic Microsoft PCL 6 Class Driver.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, all I need to do in order to attach a pipeline filter to a driver is to place the dll for the filter in the same location as the driver files and update the corresponding pipelineconfig.xml to reflect information from the sample pipeline filter, which I have done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Filters>
<Filter     dll  = "MSxpsPCL6.dll" clsid="{3821E518-33AF-4d17-92B3-28EB410D46B6}" name="Microsoft XPS to PCL6">
    <Input    guid = "{4d47a67c-66cc-4430-850e-daf466fe5bc4}" comment="IID_IPrintReadStream" />
    <Output   guid = "{65bb7f1b-371e-4571-8ac7-912f510c1a38}" comment="IID_IPrintWriteStream" />
  </Filter>
    <Filter dll="WdkPipelineFilter.dll" clsid="{5f5460d2-b313-44ca-82e4-37f83d793999}" name="StreamFilter">
    <Input    guid = "{4d47a67c-66cc-4430-850e-daf466fe5bc4}" comment="IID_IPrintReadStream" />
    <Output   guid = "{65bb7f1b-371e-4571-8ac7-912f510c1a38}" comment="IID_IPrintWriteStream" />
  </Filter>
</Filters>
```

I've tried a few different variations of positioning with the filter excerpt for the PCL 6 dll and the sample WDK dll - putting the WDK before and after the PCL 6 one as well as removing the PCL 6 one altogether - however, no matter what I do any print jobs I send through this driver stall in the print queue, creating 0kb spool files that never make it to the printer. I've also tried calling the XPS filter built into the sample with the same result.

I think there is something important I am missing but I can't put my finger on what it is. If anyone has any ideas on what could be going wrong or resources they can direct me to I would appreciate it.

Comment: did you find a solution? same problem!

Comment: No, I just posted this the other day and haven't gotten any responses. I also created a post on the Windows Dev Forum at the link below. If I find a solution I will post it here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/35be3add-4b13-4e8e-903a-9d1dc4e4aa27/how-to-connect-a-windows-print-driver-pipeline-filter?forum=wdk#35be3add-4b13-4e8e-903a-9d1dc4e4aa27

Comment: Would you please share the solution, if any.